# Apache Spark: JSON to DataFrame Exception in Java

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark. I am trying to read a json file and convert it to a DataFrame.

```
public void groupJsonString(SparkSession spark) {
    Dataset<Row> studentRecord = 
          spark.read().json("/home/sparkJsonFiles/etlFinalJson.json");
    studentRecord.printSchema();
}
```

The json file contains the below json

> {"name":"Hello"}

**When I run this code. I get the following exception. I am not able to understand what is the issue.**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal
>   pattern component: XXX    at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.parsePattern(FastDatePrinter.java:282)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.init(FastDatePrinter.java:149)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDatePrinter.(FastDatePrinter.java:142)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.(FastDateFormat.java:384)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.(FastDateFormat.java:369)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:91)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat$1.createInstance(FastDateFormat.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FormatCache.getInstance(FormatCache.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateFormat.getInstance(FastDateFormat.java:165)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions.(JSONOptions.scala:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.json.JSONOptions.(JSONOptions.scala:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat.inferSchema(JsonFileFormat.scala:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$7.apply(DataSource.scala:177)
>     at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.getOrInferFileFormatSchema(DataSource.scala:176)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
>     at
>   Spark.spark_demo.JSONGrouping.groupJsonString(JSONGrouping.java:24)
>     at Spark.spark_demo.JSONGrouping.main(JSONGrouping.java:18) 17/12/05
>   17:28:55 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
>   17/12/05 17:28:55 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at
>   http://192.168.1.30:4040 17/12/05 17:28:55 INFO
>   MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint
>   stopped! 17/12/05 17:28:55 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
>   17/12/05 17:28:55 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped 17/12/05
>   17:28:55 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped 17/12/05
>   17:28:55 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:
>   OutputCommitCoordinator stopped! 17/12/05 17:28:55 INFO SparkContext:
>   Successfully stopped SparkContext 17/12/05 17:28:55 INFO
>   ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called 17/12/05 17:28:55 INFO
>   ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory
>   /tmp/spark-2aeffac1-9dcd-4014-b821-a7737a4c5678

Comment: Why is it throwing `Illegal pattern : XXX` ?

Comment: Not able to figure out why.

Comment: check maven dependencies,  whether you have multiple versions of the apache common lang

Comment: Found the solution. Had to add the timestamp format. 
              Dataset<Row> studentRecord = spark.read() 
                .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ") 
 .json("/home/sparkJsonFiles/etlFinalJson.json");

Comment: @user2749142  solve my problem,thank you